# sql while loop .net parsing values via a hidden variable to javascript function to create chart

Tags: javascript, c#, sql

Looping through a stored procedure in .NET using SQLDataReader. Using a while loop to read the rows in the reader. Created a div with a uniqueID (int i = 0) on each loop. Retrieved data from stored procedure first row, tenth column
and stored the value in a hidden variable. I then call a javascript function to create a chart using this value in that div and then increment the i value.

I have noticed after this the loop goes to the next row and the hidden variable gets replaced with the second row value and the javascript gets called again. It looks like in the loop it is creating a unique div each time but not calling the javascript function and putting the chart in each unique div. It seems to only put it in the first div and end up with only one chart with the last value from the reader only.

```
private void ConstructBoxPlot()
{
    //currentstatus = txt1.Value;
    //currentstatus = currentstatus.Replace("\"", "");

    string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].cr_fe_KPI_RPT_Summary", cn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubTeamNo", SubTeam);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Month", Month);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", Year);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportPeriod", ReportPeriod);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@controlID", ControlID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PracticeGroupID", PracticeGroup);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Instructor", SearchInput.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MeasureID", 0);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cn.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


    var chartValues = new List<string>();
    var chartValues2 = new List<string>();
     int i = 0;
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {


            // We create our new div
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl newDiv = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
            newDiv.ID = "container" + i; //<---Give and ID to the div, very important!
            newDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "pagebr"); //<---Apply a css class if wanted
            div2.Controls.Add(newDiv); //<---Add the new div to our already existing div

            string name = reader.GetString(0);             

            if (name != "Total")
            {


                string str = reader["ChartData"].ToString();
                string a = reader["MeasureDesc"].ToString();

                string[] strList = str.Split(',');

                // convert it in json
                dataStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(strList, Formatting.None);

                hiddenvariable.Value = dataStr;
                hiddenvariablemeasuredesc.Value = a;

                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyFunc", "CreateBoxPlot(" + i + ");", true);

                i = i + 1;
                chartValues.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {

    }

    reader.Close(); // close the reader
    cn.Close();


}
```

javascript (snippet):

function CreateBoxPlot(number) {

```
var hv = $('#hiddenvariable' + number).val();
console.log(hv);
var hvmeasure = $('#hiddenvariablemeasuredesc' + number).val();
console.log(hvmeasure);
var hvtarget = $('#hiddenvariabletarget' + number).val();

var chart;
var titleText = hvmeasure;
//var subTitleText = 'Test Chart Subtitle';
var type = 'boxplot';
var data = [JSON.parse(hv).map(item => parseInt(item))]; //Doesnt work in IE

var id = "container" + number;
console.log(id);
var $container = $("<div id='"+number+"'>").appendTo(document.body);

$(function () {
    $(id).highcharts({
        chart: { type: type, inverted: true},
        title: { text: hvmeasure },
        //subtitle: { text: subTitleText },
        renderTo: $container,
        legend: { enabled: false },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like, you have one hidden element on your page. You need to create a new hidden element for each

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl newDiv = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
```

Create a hidden control element and add it to `newDiv` element

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputHidden  hiddenElement = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputHidden();
hiddenElement.Id={IDforthisField};
hiddenElement.Value = dataStr;  // <--------- Assign the value here

newDiv.Controls.Add(hiddenElement); // <--- Then add to the div element 
`
```

I hope I am able to answer your question

Comment: This doesnt seem to work - i have created a new hidden element in the .net code but the javascript doesnt work at all now - it doesnt even plot one chart. Updated my question with the javascript code as well